# events of inappbrowser is not fired for windows phone 8

Tags: cordova-2.0.0

I am using cordova 2.4.0. inappbrowser . but events are not being fired in that.

var ref =  window.open(url, '_blank');

ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function() { alert("ref"); });

Page get opened in inappbrowser. but event doesnt fire.

Comment: Which phone platform? Instead of using 'alert', try the PhoneGap Notification API.